# Closing an application on touch

Tags: android, onclick, touch, android-videoview

I've got a very basic Android application that I've been writing in Android Studio.  Firstly the purpose of the app is when launched to play a video full screen on loop until the screen is touched and the application exits.  It's essentially being used as a screensaver for a digital signage installation.

I've got the below code which handles playing the video but cannot seem to get any code for exiting on touch to work.  I am a bit of a novice when it comes to Android development.

```
package halifax.screensaver.screensaver;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        VideoView videoView = findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        Uri uri=Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.hab2);
        videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
        videoView.requestFocus();

        videoView.start();                  
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried setting an onclick on your videoview and finishing the activity?

```
videoView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        finish();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Set an OnClickListener and call `finish()` to exit the app and display the screen that was open before your activity was launched. If you want to go to a previously opened activity in your own app call `onBackPressed()`. Or if you want the user to get the home screen/launcher call the intent:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Use `setOnTouchListener` for touch event of videoview

```
videoView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                finish();
                return false;
            }
        });
```